# PDFminer, LTCurve TypeError when getting LTTextLine

Tags: python, pdfminer

i am using this code

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator

fp = open('yourpdf.pdf', 'rb')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
pages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)

for page in pages:
    print('Processing next page...')
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    for obj in layout:
        for lobj in obj:
           text =  lobj.get_text()
            print(' text: %s' % text))
```

i am using this docs: http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html#layout

I dont know why i am getting `TypeError: 'LTCurve' object is not iterable` any idea?  i think it could be because LTCurve and LTTextLine which i am trying to get are on parallel positions, how to solve it?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

solved!
i had to show the way from which place data should goes using 'if isinstance(lobj, LTTextBox)' (because LTTextLine is connected with LTTextBOX) and then i had to show that i need data from LTTextLine .
code:

```
for page in pages:
    print('Processing next page...')
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    for obj in layout:
        if isinstance(obj,LTTextBox):
           for lobj in obj:
              if isinstance(lobj,LTTextLine):
                  text =  lobj.get_text()
                   print(' text: %s' % text))
```